# Экспортируемый Eclipse apk файл не устанавливается

Tags: android, eclipse, export

Здравствуйте. Пишу программу под api10, программа работает и генерируемый Eclipse-ом .apk с debug ключом прекрасно устанавливается как самим Eclipse-ом так и ручками с флешки. А вот результат экспорта (**File** -> **Export...** || *right click to project* -> **Android Tools** -> **Export Signed Application Package...**) при установке не выдаёт ошибок, а просто заканчивается сообщением "**Приложение не установлено**".
Пробовал создать ключ через командную строку и самим Eclipse-ом через интерфейс, никакой разницы.

ADT 22.6.3,
Fly IQ238,
Android 2.3.5

Не знаю нужны ли какие-либо исходники, если нужны выложу

Comment: исходники точно не надо выкладывать...    
попробуйте на другой дивайс установить    
или на эмулятор, на пример...

Comment: @metalurgus Попробовал - запросто встало на другом девайсе с 4ым андроидом на борту. Работоспособность не проверял, всё таки приложение писалось под api10, но это и не важно в контексте задачи. Так почему же не устанавливается на 2ой?
Кстати полазил по LogCat, сразу после запуска установки выводится это:
I/ActivityManager(279): Displayed com.android.packageinstaller/.InstallAppProgress: +175ms
W/ActivityManager(279): No content provider found for: 

Может это что-то значит? Поверхностый гуглинг особо не помог

Comment: Попробовал разные версии JDK (7u55 -> 6u45 -> 6u35). Результата нет, по прежнему версия с debug ключом устанавливается, с моим нет, вопрос открыт.

Comment: может быть у вас в приложении есть какие-то требования, которые не выполнены для Флая? на пример, наличие передней камеры, или GPS?

Comment: и официальная ли прошивка стоит на флае?

Comment: @metalurgus прошивка официальная, телефон из коробки. Из разрешений ничего особенного, да и дебаг версия работает же. 
Вот список разрешений:
android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE
android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED
android.permission.INTERNET
android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE
android.permission.VIBRATE
Была версия, что проблема из-за отсутствия лаунч активности, но назначение лаунч на PreferenceActivity делу не помогло

Answer (score 1, accepted):

О господи. Очень хочется материться - похоже я дебил( я пытался установить версию, подписанную мной, ПОВЕРХ версии с дебаг ключом( Естественно ничего не получалось. Удалил дебаг, запустил установку своей и всё прекрасно встало.
Это и есть решение.

Comment: Минус в копилку Eclipse, в такой ситуации Intellij IDEA автоматом предлагается снести приложение и установить новое. И что самое приятное, IDEA сама все это делает.